Digital Ocean Audio file not playing on iOS app audio player
I am making an application where I want to play a recording on my application. We are using Digital Ocean SPACES OBJECT STORAGE to store the recordings.
Now to I am getting recording url from api as:

With CDN end point:
https://2nd-line.nyc3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/recordings/RE01d26d4b1f68485088ca35d3cd6fa340.mp3
With Origin endpoint:
https://2nd-line.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/recordings/RE01d26d4b1f68485088ca35d3cd6fa340.mp3

Now on IOS side I am handling this with below code.
This is the helper class:
import AVFoundation
import UIKit 
class MusicPlayerHelper:NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    static let shared = MusicPlayerHelper()
    private var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    var musicCompleteEvent: (()->())?
    
    func loadAudio(from url: URL) {
        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            player?.prepareToPlay()
            player?.delegate = self
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error loading audio: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
    
    
    func getDurationSync() -> TimeInterval? {
        return player?.duration
    }
 
    func getCurrentTime() -> TimeInterval {
        return player?.currentTime ?? 0
    }
 
    func play() {
        player?.play()
    }
 
    func pause() {
        player?.pause()
    }
 
    func stop() {
        player?.stop()
    }
    
    func trimmingMusicStop() {
        player?.stop()
    }
 
    func seekTo(time: TimeInterval) {
        player?.currentTime = time
    }
    
    func forward() {
        player?.currentTime += 5
    }
 
    func backward() {
        player?.currentTime -= 5
    }
    
    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        // Call the completion handler when the audio finishes
        musicCompleteEvent?()
    }
}

And I am calling in viewController like this:
private func loadAudioFileIfNeeded() {
        guard let audioUrlString = audioUrl else { return }
        NetworkManager.shared.downloadFile(from: audioUrlString) { [weak self] isSuccess, filePath in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            if isSuccess, let filePath = filePath {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let localURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
                    self.setupAudioPlayer(with: localURL)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func setupAudioPlayer(with audioURL: URL) {
        musicPlayerHelper.loadAudio(from: audioURL)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.playingIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self.playingIndicator.isHidden = true
            self.sliderPlayPauseBtn.isHidden = false
            self.cropBtn.isHidden = false
            if let duration = self.musicPlayerHelper.getDurationSync() {
                self.sliderMusicEndTime = duration
                self.waveMusicEndTime = duration
                self.slider.maximumValue = Float(duration)
                self.waveEndPlaybackTime.text = self.formatTime(self.waveMusicEndTime)
                self.sliderEndPlaybackTime.text = self.formatTime(self.sliderMusicEndTime)
                self.setupSliderAndLabels()
            }
        }
    }

But I am getting below error:

Error loading audio: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1685348671)

Although this url is playing well on web browser and mobile browser.
I tried different git codes but same issue. Even VLC app also is not able to play this

This was the issue from our server side code. So we were getting recordings in .wav format but we were saving them in .mp3. We change this and now able to play . Thanks
